# Selenium 2 /WebDriver Migration Issue WebDriver Does not select correct elements

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am in the process of migrating my test suite from the Selenium 1 to WebDriver. I've come across a problem clicking on elements on a page which contains a map of the USA clickable states.

Using Selenium 1 I would do the following to select a particular state from the map.

```
selenium.click("css=area[alt=North Carolina]");
```

In Selenium 2 I'm converting this to

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("area[alt=North Carolina]")).click();
```

WebDriver actually selects a different State. This is not a timing issue, a state is selected it is just the incorrect state. I've tried switching out cssselector for xpath with the same result.

Not sure if this is related to [this issue](http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver/browse_thread/thread/d06f6789deb29ce8)

OS : Win XP

Browsers: Tested on IE 8 and FF 5 & 6

Selenium : 2.5.0

Example of page code

```
<area alt="California" shape="POLY" coords="10,60,29,68,25,98,56,146,51,167,17,138,3,70"   href="javascript:LoadCategory('CA');">
```

Comment: Are you positive that these states are unique elements? List<WebElement> states = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("area[alt=North Carolina]")); System.out.println(states.size); //is this 1? Is there a public website where I can try this out?

Comment: Interesting. If I perform the test you provided on a state without a space in the name (California, etc) I get 1. If I use a state with a space I get an error.  `"An invalid or illegal string was specified"` Still, even using this method to select a state without a space it still selects the wrong state (or nothing at all). Here is an example website : [link](http://www.servsafe.com/catalog/starterscategories.aspx)

Comment: Following up, if the alt tag contains a space you have to wrap it for webdriver to locate it. I.E. `(By.cssSelector("area[alt='North Carolina']"))` Alas, still not selecting the correct element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the HTML for the page you provided, it seems that there are individual pages for states like CA,AZ,OH etc. There are some other states (majority of them) like NM, MT etc all have common pages. As far as webdriver is concerned, I am not sure why it's not clicking on the right element. I wrote something like below that works for me. You will have to extend this logic for other states.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.servsafe.com/catalog/starterscategories.aspx");
Selenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl());
selenium.windowMaximize();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("javascript:LoadCategory('CA');");
```

Similarly, you can do it for other states that have individual pages, like

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("javascript:LoadCategory('AZ');");
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("javascript:LoadCategory('FL');");
```

For states that have common pages,

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("javascript:LoadCategory();");
```

Comment: This solution works for the page but seems sub optimal. WebDriver should be able to "click" on these separate elements, seems like this might be a bug in webdriver as it functions correctly in Selenium 1.

Comment: I agree. You might want to post the question on webdriver google groups as well - http://groups.google.com/group/webdriver

Comment: @Brett I would suggest you to open a defect here http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/list You do have a public website where developers can reproduce the issue and is an ideal situation to debug things and fix. Perhaps it will solve other obscure issues around click() faced by other community members as well.

Comment: thanks! I opened a ticket http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2354&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 0):

I make a suggestion to use Javascript click() method.

example,

```
new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver,"").assignId("css=area[alt='California']", "California");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('California').click()");
```

Comment: document.getElementById("foo").click is not a function. For browsers like Firefox, Chrome, you will have to create a click event like var evObj = document.createEvent('MouseEvents'); evObj.initEvent('click',true,true); element.dispatchEvent(evObj); For IE it is conceptually different. This should do, element.fireEvent('onclick'); I tried this on Brett's website and it did not work for me.